# Dynamically generate method that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to write a wrapper for the new MongoDB driver to work with code written for the old driver.

The old way of using Mongo in PHP was like this:

```
$connection = new Mongo('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1/theDatabaseYouWantToConnectTo');
$db = $connection->theDatabaseYouWantToConnectTo;
$collection = $db->aCollectionYouWantToDoStuffWith;
$collection->insert(array(
    'someColumnName' => 'someDataForTheCell'
));
```

My question is, how does these parts work?

```
$db = $connection->theDatabaseYouWantToConnectTo;
$collection = $db->aCollectionYouWantToDoStuffWith;
```

Obviously `theDatabaseYouWantToConnectTo` and `aCollectionYouWantToDoStuffWith` are NOT methods, so how would my wrapper class understand what these are?

Here is kind of a skeleton for the wrapper class I'm trying to write.

```
class Mongo{

    var $native_mongo_instance;

    function __construct($uri){

        $native_mongo_instance = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($uri);

        $this->set_native_mongo_instance($native_mongo_instance);

    }

    public function set_native_mongo_instance($native_mongo_instance){

        $this->native_mongo_instance = $native_mongo_instance;

    }

    public function get_native_mongo_instance(){

        return $this->native_mongo_instance;

    }

    public function find(){


    }

    public function insert(){


    }

    public function remove(){


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a [full reference](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.magic.php) of magic methods in PHP. The one that you're looking for is `__get()` ([here's](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy/blob/cb5c8da5a8e6695881f63dc39c853740c12c29ce/db.c#L1397) C code of the legacy driver).

Also to not reinvent the wheel (or for learning purposes), you may take a look at [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) which provides old API atop new driver and library.

Comment: I was looking for one, but i kept searching for "wrapper", not "adapter". This is WAY easier for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll also have to really check out Magic Methods for the future. I really appreciate that. Thank You!